# How to solve system?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve the system $$ \{\sqrt{x-y}+\sqrt{x-2} = 2, \sqrt{x^2+y^2-xy(x-y)}+\sqrt{y(x-y)} = \sqrt{8(x-y-1)}\}$$ over the reals? I can derive $x=1/16\,{y}^{2}-1/4\,y+9/4$ from the first equation.

Comment: Can we try $x-2=4\cos^4\phi, x-y=4\sin^4\phi$ from the first? as both radicals are $\ge0$

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee : And then what?

Comment: Have you tried evaluating the second expression using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html and

Comment: @ lab bhatttacharjee: Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a good way, but this does give the answers.

Letting $A=x^2+y^2-xy(x-y), B=y(x-y), C=8(x-y-1)$, then we get from the second equation,
$$A+B+2\sqrt{AB}=C$$$$\Rightarrow 4AB=(C-A-B)^2$$

Also, from the first equation, we get $$x=\frac 1{16}y^2+\frac 14 y+\frac 94.$$ (note! you are wrong.)

Now, if you substitute it for the last equation we got, then you'll get an equation of $y$. And wolfram-alpha will give you the answers. Don't forget to pay attention for the domain of $y$.

Maybe you don't like this way, but calculation does tell you the answer.

Comment: I find this way interesting. Thank you for the correction. Can you elaborate your answer, writing down the equation in $y$?

Comment: I'm reluctant to do that:) Why don't you do that yourself since you've already known how to do it?

Comment: @MarkiyanHirnyk : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-y%5E%2810%29%2B18y%5E9-145y%5E8-13648y%5E6%2B51072y%5E5-661344y%5E4%2B1624320y%5E3-3747840y%5E2%2B5776896y-1597696%3D0

Comment: This is $$-{y}^{10}+18\,{y}^{9}-145\,{y}^{8}+1968\,{y}^{7}-13648\,{y}^{6}+51072
\,{y}^{5}-661344\,{y}^{4}+1624320\,{y}^{3}-3747840\,{y}^{2}+5776896\,y
-1597696=0.
  $$ And then what?

Comment: I don't find the usage of WA satisfactory. The numerical solution can be found from the original system.

Comment: I agree with you, but so far I can't. Then, what will you do?